# JupyterLab - NameError: name 'data_df ' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I used a pyspark kernel to download some data from AWS-S3 and convert to Pandas:

my first cell looks like this:

```
liq_banco = pd.DataFrame()
meu_diretorio = 's3://bucket/'
meu_arquivo = 'file_name'

from_s3 = spark.read.format('csv').option('header', 'true').option('sep', ';').load(f'{meu_diretorio}/{meu_arquivo}.csv')

data_df = from_s3.toPandas()
```

my second cell looks like this:

```
%matplotlib inline
print(liq_banco)
```

but, when i tried print os plot graphics in another cell... jupyterlab show this message:

```
'NameError: name 'data_df ' is not defined'
```

data_df is a DataFrame with data.

Who can I fixed it?

sorry my english...

I tried use magic commands, but i didn't success.

Comment: are you sure the first cell ran? did the line `data_df = from_s3.toPandas()` run to completion?

Comment: i belive that go to the end, becouse didn't show any message. i just used this line in anothers projects.

Comment: if i use 'print' in fist cell, i can see the data from 'data_df'. the problem is when i wolf like use in another cell into jupyterlab.

Comment: `'NameError: name 'data_df ' is not defined'`. Note the extra space after `data_df` in that message. Maybe you put an extra space in the cell with the code that plots the graphics?

Comment: @slothrop that's interesting, but i think like the error message would remove that trailing space because spaces in variable names aren't allowed

Comment: Spaces in variable names aren't allowed, but let's say I have a function like `def f(name): return globals()[name]`. That would throw (admittedly with a different type of exception) if called with a forbidden variable name like `'data_df '`. I guess it would be useful to see exactly what the code is in the cell that displays the graphics.

Comment: a million sorry, the message don't has a sapce. 'NameError: name 'data_df' is not defined'

Comment: how can i declare a global variable? Is it possivel use this kind variable on jupyterlab?

Comment: I tried use: globals()['teste'] = data_df and after tried print (2nd cell) and the erro was the same.